# Sign pdf file digitally in perl

Tags: perl, pdf, digital-signature

I want to sign .pdf file digitally and after that to create attached signature file and detached signature file, using Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA.
This is what I did:

1. Initialization

   ```
   my $s_pdf_file_to_sign = 'pdf_file_to_sign';
   my $s_private_key_file = 'private_key_file';
   my $s_cert_file = 'certificate_file';
   ```
2. Read .pdf file content

   ```
   my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
   $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat $s_pdf_to_sign;
   open FILE, "<$s_pdf_to_sign" or die "no such file";
   binmode FILE;
   my $s_pdf_to_sign_string;
   read FILE, $s_pdf_to_sign_string, $size;
   close FILE;
   ```
3. Read private key content:

   ```
   ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
   $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat $s_private_key;
   open FILE, "<$s_private_key" or die "no such file";
   binmode FILE;
   my $s_private_key_content;
   read FILE, $s_private_key_content, $size;
   close FILE;
   ```
4. Create private_key object:

   ```
   my $s_private_key_string = $s_private_key_content;
   my $oref_rsa_priv = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($s_private_key_content) or die "new_private_key error";
   ```
5. Sign pdf file content:

   ```
   my $signature = $oref_rsa_priv->sign($s_pdf_content);
   ```

Could someone tell me what contains $signature variable? What should I do to create the attached and detached signatures?

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pdf/5161/integrated-pdf-signatures/18248/how-integrated-pdf-signatures-are-integrated#t=201609091349325346354) and documents linked from the remarks there to understand how integrated PDF signatures are "integrated".